# True/False: If v is a leaf in every spanning tree resulting from DFS(s), then v is a leaf in every spanning tree resulting from BFS(s)

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, search-algorithms

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a connected undirected graph. Let $s \in V$ be a vertex in the graph.

True/False: If $v$ is a leaf in every spanning tree resulting from DFS(s), then $v$ is a leaf in every spanning tree resulting from BFS(s).

I assume that this one is True, and I think that because if $v$ is a leaf in every DFS(s), that means $v$ has no children on $G$ graph, but I struggle to prove it.

I'd like to get some help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $v$ is a leaf in the spanning tree given by BFS($v$) if and only if $v$ is a leaf in $G$ (by definition of BFS).

That said, you should try with a graph $G$ that is a circular graph (or cycle graph), and any vertex $v=s$.

If you want an answer when $v \neq s$, then we can indeed show that if $v$ is a leaf in any DFS($s$), then $v$ is a leaf in $G$ (and so $v$ is a leaf in any BFS($s$)).

Indeed, suppose $v$ is not a leaf in $G$. Then it means that $v$ has two neighbors $x$ and $y$. If we suppose that $v$ is a leaf in any DFS($s$), then consider such a DFS where $x$ is explored before $y$. We have now two possibilities:

- $v$ is explored before $x$. Since $v\neq s$, that means that $v$ is not a leaf in the resulting spanning tree (because in this tree, $v$ has two neighbors);
- $v$ is explored after $x$. Then a graph traversal similar to this one until $x$, which then explores $v$ then $y$ then continues the DFS from $y$ would still be a DFS. In the resulting spanning tree, $v$ has two neighbors, so $v$ is not a leaf.

We proved that $v$ not a leaf in $G$ implies there exists a DFS($s$) where $v$ is not a leaf, or equivalently $v$ is a leaf in every DFS($s$) implies $v$ is a leaf in $G$ implies $v$ is a leaf in every DFS($s$).

Comment: Note that $v$ and $s$ are different...

Comment: @user144930 Since you wanted the result for any $v$ and any $s$, a counter-example in the particular case of $v = s$ can still help you.

Comment: In this case, when $v=s$ there is a counter example, I agree. But what happens when $v \ne s$?

Comment: @user144930 I edited my answer.

Comment: Can someone explain this point to me again, please? *v is explored after x. Then a graph traversal similar to this one until x, which then explores v then y then continues the DFS from y would still be a DFS. In the resulting spanning tree, v has two neighbors, so v is not a leaf. Also, why is that matter that v != s?

Comment: Thank you very much Nathaniel! I appreciate that!

Comment: I found an error with your second statement: What happens if $v$ is explored after $x$ and after $y$? we have a path $x-y-v$ which makes $v$ a leaf.

Comment: @user144930 If $v$ is explored after $y$, the second case applies: you can go back to when $x$ is explored, and instead go to $v$ then $y$ (possible in a DFS because neither $v$ nor $y$ is explored at that time).

Comment: @Nathaniel I do not agree with that, because you can't simply go back to $x$ - you do not know in which order DFS chooses its path.

Comment: The idea is to create a new DFS order given an existing one. When exploring a new vertex, the DFS has as many choices to continue as this vertex has neighbours. So the "new" DFS will continue with $v$ when exploring $x$, and with $y$ when exploring $v$.